# Configure Angular to read .mrt files as XML to fix error ' Unexpected token < in JSON'

Tags: angular

I'm using Stimulsoft to generate a report in my .NET Core application,report file has .mrt extension and it is a xml file.
In development mode report work but after I build and publish my application I got:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

renaming the .mrt file to xml fix the error in my app but If want to edit the report,Stimulsoft designer doesn't recognize xml as report only .mrt extension,
so how can I configure Angular to read .mrt files as .xml?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using in .csproj file after build command to rename mrt files to xml:

```
<Target Name="GenerateContentFilesAfterPublish" BeforeTargets="AfterPublish">
        <Exec Command="ren $(SolutionDir)bin\Release\PublishOutput\ClientApp\dist\reports\*.mrt *.xml" />
</Target>
```

then in my angular project I load report files using  isDevMode()

```
..
 this.report.loadFile(fnGetRepoPath('myreport'));
...
import {  isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
...
 fnGetRepoPath(n: string): string {
    return './reports/' + n + (isDevMode() ? '.mrt' : '.xml');
  }
```